# How to make a column based on previous values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**I have a data frame:**

```
user_id      url
111          google.com
111          youtube.com
111          youtube.com
111          google.com
111          stackoverflow.com
111          google.com
222          twitter.com
222          google.com
222          twitter.com
```

I want to create a column that will show the fact of visiting this URL before.

**Desired output:**

```
user_id      url                 target
111          google.com          0
111          youtube.com         0
111          youtube.com         1
111          google.com          1
111          stackoverflow.com   0
111          google.com          1
222          twitter.com         0
222          google.com          0
222          twitter.com         1
```

I can do this with a loop but it doesn't look good. Is it possible to make it with pandas?

Comment: I believe that this is considered part of the input data as the sequence imply some order. If you only need the total you can count based on the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['target'] = df.duplicated().astype(int)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   user_id                url  target
0      111         google.com       0
1      111        youtube.com       0
2      111        youtube.com       1
3      111         google.com       1
4      111  stackoverflow.com       0
5      111         google.com       1
6      222        twitter.com       0
7      222         google.com       0
8      222        twitter.com       1
```

Comment: Wow, It looks pretty easy

Answer (score 3):

```
df['target'] =df.groupby(['user_id','url']).cumcount().gt(0).astype(int)

    user_id            url      target
0      111         google.com       0
1      111        youtube.com       0
2      111        youtube.com       1
3      111         google.com       1
4      111  stackoverflow.com       0
5      111         google.com       1
6      222        twitter.com       0
7      222         google.com       0
8      222        twitter.com       1
```